# Google IoT API 403 error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**using this sample code**: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client/http_example

**getting the below error.**
error: {u'error': {u'status': u'PERMISSION_DENIED', u'message': u'The caller does not have permission', u'code': 403}}

I've generated RSA key pairs one which I've used set the cert for the device in the cloud, the other private key I pass into the python script.
I thought it'd look for the GCLOUD_APPLICAITION_CREDENTIALS but seemingly only uses the private key as means of verification. Anyone face this issue before?

*Probably* highly relevant I'm passing in proxy details to the put/get requests which are fine and valid but may cause issues.

**Okay so i'm now running it from the Google Cloud Platform console, same error, what dumb thing have I done? Double and triple checked keys.**

**Fixed check comments.**

Comment: Had to make myself the owner for the service, got it going now.

Comment: Nice to read this half the way to replicate the tutorial :D

Comment: Was running from a VM, wasn't keeping itself sync'd time wise, causing horrible oauth issues.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, but in my case was that I needed to add the `--cloud_region` parameter.